# Google analytics embed api deauthorize

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I followed [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide) on how to set up a google analytics dashboard on my site using javascript and it is working.

I've only had to click the authenticate button once several days ago and it continues to keep me logged in. I haven't found a way to add a "log out" or "deauthorize" button. How do I do that?

I'm looking at the [documentation for gapi.analytics.auth](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#auth-options) and see authorize and isAuthorized, but nothing for logout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Embed API does not currently support a sign out feature, but you should be able to accomplish this manually by calling the underlying `gapi.auth.signOut()` method yourself.

Note there may be some weirdness if you try to log back in without refreshing the page (I'm not sure because I haven't tested this fully).

#### Update (11/10/2015):

The Embed API's [auth component](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#auth) now officially supports a `signOut` method, so you can just use that instead.

Comment: Thank you. That works. Not sure why I didn't think of it! Oddly because I'm a newbie here I can't upvote your response.

Comment: The analytics.signOut works fine  but when I call authorize again it authorizes with the same user. Is there a way to authorize with different user?

Comment: Hmmm, I usually have different Chrome profiles that I browse the web with if I need to use Google services for different Google accounts. That's honestly what I'd recommend here. Otherwise you'd just have to log out completely.

Comment: I made a call to revoke the app authorization after signOut, that way the user gets to login again with another user

Comment: @ArjunRamesh did you use `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().disconnect()`? I'd recommend using that if you're not. You can actually use it instead of `gapi.analytics.auth.signOut()` and it will *still* trigger the `signOut` event in the Embed API because the Embed API is listening for changes to `gapi.auth2` under the hood.

Comment: @PhilipWalton I am using gapi.auth not auth2, because of which the disconnect method fails, I did not get time to investigate more on that.

Comment: The Embed API now uses gapi.auth2, so that would explain why.